# ViewModel with LiveData and MutableList not Updating in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

Am new to Android Development in general and especially with Jetpack Compose and its ways of updating the Composables. I have a iOS background with lots of SwiftUI though.

Anyways, I have the following app

[image]

The Composables look like this:

```
@Composable
fun Greeting() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxHeight()2
            .fillMaxWidth(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly
    ) {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly
        ) {
            IncrementButton()
            DecrementButton()
        }
        PressedText()
        SizeText()
    }
}

@Composable
fun PressedText() {
    val myViewModel: MyViewModel = viewModel()
    val myNumber by myViewModel.number.observeAsState()
    Text(text = "Pressed: $myNumber")
}

@Composable
fun SizeText() {
    val myViewModel: MyViewModel = viewModel()
    val myList by myViewModel.list.observeAsState()
    Text(text = "Size: ${myList?.size}")
}

@Composable
fun IncrementButton() {
    val myViewModel: MyViewModel = viewModel()
    Button(onClick = myViewModel::add) {
        Text("Add")
    }
}

@Composable
fun DecrementButton() {
    val myViewModel: MyViewModel = viewModel()
    Button(onClick = myViewModel::remove) {
        Text("Remove")
    }
}
```

The view model I am using looks like this:

```
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val _number = MutableLiveData<Int>()
    val number: LiveData<Int> = _number

    private val _list = MutableLiveData<MutableList<Int>>()
    val list: LiveData<MutableList<Int>> = _list

    init {
        _number.value = 0
        _list.value = mutableListOf()
    }

    fun add() {
        _number.value = _number.value?.plus(1)
        _number.value?.let {
            _list.value?.add(it)
            _list.value = _list.value
        }
    }

    fun remove() {
        _number.value = _number.value?.minus(1)
        if (_list.value?.isNotEmpty() == true) {
            _list.value?.removeAt(0)
            _list.value = _list.value
        }
    }
}
```

When I press the "Add"-button the number after "Pressed" gets updated but not the number after "Size".

Am really not sure about those lines with `_list.value = _list.value` that I have from some other SO post that said to update the reference of the list.

What am I missing? Any hints highly appreciated.

Feel free to leave any comments regarding code design.

Thank you!

Comment: Stop storing a `MutableList` in the `MutableLiveData`, use `List`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `_list.value = _list.value` is a really bad idea. Depending on underlying implementation, it may work or may not. In this case it's probably compared by pointer, that's why it doesn't trigger recomposition.

Check out [Why is immutability important in functional programming](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-immutability-important-in-functional-programming).

The safe way is using non mutable list:

```
private val _list = MutableLiveData<List<Int>>()
```

And mutate it like this:

```
_list.value = _list.value?.toMutableList()?.apply {
    add(value)
}
```

By doing this, you're creating a new list each time, and this will trigger recomposition without problems.

---

Also, using `LiveData` is not required at all: if you don't have some dependencies, which makes you using it, you can go for Compose mutable state: it's much cleaner:

```
var number by mutableStateOf(0)
    private set

private val _list = mutableStateListOf<Int>()
val list: List<Int> = _list

fun add() {
    number++
    _list.add(number)
}

fun remove() {
    number--
    _list.removeAt(0)
}
```